# Необходимо вывести массив на страницу

Tags: php, sql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добрый день всем. Появилась проблемка, необходимо вывести массив на страницу, а именно значение brand_id, brand_name и parent_id, таким образом чтобы элементы строки были в связке, недвижимость на первом месте, транспорт на втором(по порядку до конца списка), а также родители имели потомков с имеющимися parent_id. Нашел решение данного вопроса, однако есть некоторые проблемы, которые попутно возникли.

```
function catalog(){
  $query = "SELECT * FROM brands ORDER BY parent_id, brand_name" ;
  $res = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_query());
  //массив категорий
  $cat = array();
  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
    if(!$row['parent_id']){
      $cat[$row['brand_id']][] = $row['brand_name'];
    }else{
      $cat[$row['parent_id']]['sub'][$row['brand_id']] = $row['brand_name'];
    }
    return $cat;
  }  
}
```

Это всё нужно для того, чтобы в итоге создать меню категорий в одном из баров. Проблема в том, что всё выполняется, только вместо выполнения всех строк, выполняется только одна.

Позже понял, что это всё из-за того, что порядок строк с исходными значениями не позволяет вывести всё по порядку, необходимо, чтобы имена были по алфавиту и родители по порядку. Теперь думаю, что делать или создавать новые имена, чтобы не нужна была сортировка или сортировать так, чтобы программа выполнялась.

Comment: Можно подробнее о выводе "в связке". Приведите пример вывода.

Comment: Для того, чтобы проверить родительская эта категория или нет используется условие. Связка - имел ввиду, что brand_id выводится вместе с brand_name, входящие в одну строку, берутся значения из той строки, где они соответствуют друг друг в одной строке, к примеру выводит недвимимость, что это 1-ый номер и является родительской категорией, то есть возвращает false

Comment: В начале мне нужно хотя бы вывести от 1-8, я там ещё изменил 5-экраны, убрал 3 в parent_id и поставил 0, чтобы хотя бы по порядку вывело, а потом буду думать, что делать с подкатегориями, то есть с 13-19

Comment: Мне это выводит на страницу. Array
(
    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Бизнес и работа
        )

)

Comment: Задача вроде простая, но не выполняется как надо, хотя вроде всё правильно...

Answer (score 1):

Для перевода подобного массива в дерево можно воспользоваться уже готовым алгоритмом, который меняет исходный массив, а ссылки на элементы, у которых нет родителей, добавляет в новый.

```
function getTreeFromArray($arr){
    $tree = array();
    foreach($arr as $id =>& $data){
        if(@$data['parent_id'] == $id){
            $tree[$id] =& $data;
        } else {
            $arr[$data['parent_id']]['childes'][$data['id']] =& $arr[$id];
        }
    }
    return $tree;
}
```

Условие - исходный массив должен быть вида

```
[1] => [
   [id] => 1, 
   ...
],
```

, то есть ключи массива должны совпадать с `id` в теле.

Если использовать PDO, этого можно добиться с флагом `FETCH_UNIQUE` и дублированием `id` в начале запроса:

```
$pdo->query('SELECT id, table.* FROM table')->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE);
```

В вашем примере исходный массив (его часть для удобства) выглядит так:

```
$arr = array(
    1 => array(
        'id' => 1,
        'brand_name' => 'Недвижимость',
        'parent_id' => 0
    ),
    2 => array(
        'id' => 2,
        'brand_name' => 'Транспорт',
        'parent_id' => 0
    ),
    3 => array(
        'id' => 3,
        'brand_name' => 'Бытовая техника',
        'parent_id' => 0
    ),
    4 => array(
        'id' => 4,
        'brand_name' => 'Бизнес и работа',
        'parent_id' => 0
    ),
    5 => array(
        'id' => 5,
        'brand_name' => 'Экраны',
        'parent_id' => 3
    )
);
```

а итоговый `echo '<pre>' . print_r( getTreeFromArray($arr) , true) . '</pre>'` так:

```
[0] => Array(
    [childes] => Array  (
        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [brand_name] => Недвижимость
                [parent_id] => 0
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [id] => 2
                [brand_name] => Транспорт
                [parent_id] => 0
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [id] => 3
                [brand_name] => Бытовая техника
                [parent_id] => 0
                [childes] => Array
                    (
                        [5] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 5
                                [brand_name] => Экраны
                                [parent_id] => 3
                            )

                    )

            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [id] => 4
                [brand_name] => Бизнес и работа
                [parent_id] => 0
            )

    )
)
```

Также, для "человеческого" вывода этого массива желательно (но необязательно), чтобы корневые элементы хранили значение parent_id равным своему id. Тогда они будут главными ветками, и дочерние будут добавляться в них.
Если будет так, как в вашем примере, у корней `parent_id = 0`, то все корневые элементы будут добавлены в пустой массив с ид 0, как сейчас.